# Data binding a table in Odata store with a chart using dxchart

Tags: javascript, jquery, data-binding, bar-chart, devextreme

Data binding using Dev express and jquery.
   Need to get table stored in odata store to bind with chart using widget dxchart.
   Error in console window :$(...).dxChart is not a function

```
var context = new DevExpress.data.ODataContext({
url: "DataService.svc/",
entities: {
    SalesEngine_Report_Pipelines:{},
    SalesEngine_Report_TopTGOs:{},
}
});

var chartOptions = {
    dataSource: {
       store: context.SalesEngine_Report_Pipelines
    },
    title: "Tempelate",
    size: {
        height: 420
    },

    series: {
        argumentField: "GroupName",
        valueField: "NumGroup",
        name: "My oranges",
        type: "bar",
    }
};
$("#chart").dxChart(chartOptions);
```

Comment: Make sure you have DevExtreme resources(javascripts, css) on a page. Check you are running your code on [$.ready](https://api.jquery.com/ready/), as well.

Comment: javascript and css files are on the page.I have used **$(function ()** in my code.I do not know how to use **$.ready** in my code and  how will it help to solve the problem.Can you elaborate it a little bit because I am totally new to this.@Sergey

Comment: 'Use $.ready' means you have to wrap your code with `$(function(){ /*..*/});` construction like in [this](https://js.devexpress.com/Demos/WidgetsGallery/Demo/Charts/SimpleArray/jQuery/Light/) demo. Also, pay attention all DevExtreme scripts are included on a page **before** your code. One more point, charts are available only in `dx.all.js`, `dx.viz.js` and `dx.viz-web.js` bundles, so you should use these files(not `dx.mobile.js` or `dx.web.js`).

Comment: I have used this $(function(){ /*..*/}); in my code.All Dev extreme scripts are included.I have included dx.viz.js bundel.Do I need to include all of the above bundels?                                                                                                                     (also I am able to use dxDataGrid to get grids, just not able to get charts using dxChart)

Comment: `dx.viz.js` is enough. Anyway, it sounds strange. And it's hard to understand what's going wrong in your case without your code. So, can you share it anywhere? I mean full html page.

Comment: BTW, what jQuery & DevExtreme version do you use?

Comment: jQuery v 3.1.1  , DevExtreme v 16.1.8 and  js bundles v 17.1.3

Comment: You shouldn't use two DevExtreme versions(16.1.8 and 17.1.3). Your html file should contain these scripts: `jquery-3.1.1.js`, `dx.all.js`(you can load it from `https://cdn3.devexpress.com/jslib/17.1.3/js/dx.all.js`). Look at this [picture](https://www.screencast.com/t/szVcY2qu). Do you have a similar markup?

Comment: Thanks.This solved my problem.@Sergey